# Add Sub Nav Menu Item to Buddy Press Menu

Tags: buddypress

I'm having trouble adding sub nav menu items to my parent menu item under Buddy Press.

The parent menu item as shown below, named **`TEST`**, shows correctly, but the tabs named **`SUB NAV`** and **`SUB NAV 2`** don’t show at all.

```
function my_setup_nav() { 
global $bp; 
$em_link = $bp->loggedin_user->domain . $bp->account->slug . '/';

# - add parent menu item    

bp_core_new_nav_item( array( 
    'name' =>  'TEST',
    'slug' =>  $bp->account->slug, 
    'position' => 10,
    ) 
); 

# - add sub nav menu items

bp_core_new_subnav_item( array( 
    'name' => 'SUB NAV',
    'slug' => 'account-sub', 
    'parent_url' =>  $em_link ,
    'parent_slug' => $bp->account->slug,
    'position' => 10,
    'item_css_id' => 'xx' 
    ) 
); 
bp_core_new_subnav_item( array( 
    'name' => 'SUB NAV 2',
    'slug' => 'account-sub-2', 
    'parent_url' =>  $em_link ,
    'parent_slug' => $bp->account->slug,
    'position' => 20,
    'item_css_id' => 'xx-2' 
    ) 
); 
} 

add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'my_setup_nav', 99 );
```

What's the correct syntax for getting the Sub Navigation items to work correctly?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Asked and Answered here:
http://buddypress.org/support/topic/create-sub-nav-menu-item-in-profile/

Did you try the suggested solution ?

Comment: I tried adding the screen function with an empty test function to no avail. If I change the slug to `$bp->profile->slug` then the Sub Nav item appears as a sub item of the Profile Parent tab but seems not to work with my custom added "TEST" parent. It seems like its a slug issue, but whether I am declaring `'slug' => $bp->account->slug` or `'slug' => 'account'` it still doesn't seem to take. When I dump the `$bp` global, I can see my parent menu item exists as it should, so that doesn't seem to be the issue. Thanks for your input thus far.

Comment: It turned out to be that the BP custom profile menu plugin was conflicting with my code or vice versa. Disabling that plugin now allows me to manually declare parent/child items correctly. Thanks for your help.